# Get all substrings between parentheses

Tags: php, preg-match-all, text-extraction

I want to extract all strings between two characters (parentheses).

```
$string = "blah blah blah (blorp) blah blah (bloop) blah blah (bam)";
```

Desired output:

```
['blorp', 'bloop', 'bam']
```

I don't need any of the blah blahs, just everything within parenthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression:

```
$string = "blah blah blah (blorp) blah blah (bloop) blah blah (bam)";
preg_match_all("/\((.*?)\)/", $string, $result_array);

print_r( $result_array[1] ); // $result_array[0] contains the matches with the parens
```

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => blorp
    [1] => bloop
    [2] => bam
)
```

My regular expression uses a non-greedy selector: `(.*?)` which means it will grab as "little" as possible. This keeps it from eating up all the `)` and grabbing everything between the opening `(` and the closing `)` how ever many words away.

Comment: Hey @doug-neiner can you help me what if I need the blah term also within the array. Is it possible to use the same preg_match_all for this by adjusting it Or I have to use explode ?
_thanks in advance_

Answer (score 2):

You could use preg_match_all with something like (just a quick draft...):

```
preg_match_all("|\([^)]+\)|", $string, $result_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

all using regex, here's one without regex

```
$string = "blah blah blah (blorp) blah blah (bloop) blah blah (bam)";
$s = explode(")",$string);
foreach ( $s as $k=>$v ){
    $m= strpos($v,"(" );
    if ($m){
        print substr( $v, $m+1  )  . "\n"  ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything in parenthesis, then you should use regular expressions. In your case, this will do the thick:

```
preg_match_all('/\(.*?\)/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

```
$matches = array();
$num_matched = preg_match_all('/\((.*)\)/U', $input, $matches);
```