# Split string between two special characters

Tags: php, arrays, regex, special-characters

**The Objective**

I want to retrieve all the emails between the special characters `< >` of the string into an array of emails

```
$list = '"momo rabit" <m.rabit@sfr.fr>, "youn" <youn@hotmail.fr>, "yourmail" <yourmail@gmail.com>, "yovan" <y.yovan@orange.fr>, "popol" <popol.paul@alice.fr>';
```

**What I tried**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850561/split-string-between-two-characters), it should work.

```
$list = htmlspecialchars($list);
preg_match_all("/<(.*?)>/", $list, $list_step);
var_dump($list_step); // Return empty arrays
```

**I also tried without success**

[preg-split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

[str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: because the preg_match seems to keep only the characters between "..." and dismiss the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy. The [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) converts the `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. So either change the regex or remove that function.

```
$list = '"momo rabit" <m.rabit@sfr.fr>, "youn" <youn@hotmail.fr>, "yourmail" <yourmail@gmail.com>, "yovan" <y.yovan@orange.fr>, "popol" <popol.paul@alice.fr>'; 
//$list = htmlspecialchars($list);
preg_match_all("/<(.*?)>/", $list, $list_step);
var_dump($list_step); // Return empty arrays
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/VUY1U

Alternative:

```
$list = '"momo rabit" <m.rabit@sfr.fr>, "youn" <youn@hotmail.fr>, "yourmail" <yourmail@gmail.com>, "yovan" <y.yovan@orange.fr>, "popol" <popol.paul@alice.fr>'; 
$list = htmlspecialchars($list);
preg_match_all("/&lt;(.*?)&gt;/", $list, $list_step);
var_dump($list_step); // Return empty arrays
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/gI07A